# Index Out Of Range exception on " examScores[countOfExams] = double.Parse(examScoresTextBox.Text);"

Tags: c#

When I press the click event to add array values, it gives me an out of index exception error. I'd like to know why it's happening and how to fix it, thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ArrayTestCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double scoreInput = 0;
        int countOfExams = 0;
        double[] examScores;
        double count = 0;
        //field array declare


        private void enterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countOfExams = int.Parse(numOfExamsTextBox.Text);
            examScores = new double[countOfExams];
            examLabel.Text = "Exam 1: ";


            label1.Visible = false;
            numOfExamsTextBox.Visible = false;
            enterBtn.Visible = false;

            examLabel.Visible = true;
            examScoresTextBox.Visible = true;
            addBtn.Visible = true;


        }



        private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            examLabel.Text = "Exam " + (countOfExams +1) + ":";
            examScores[countOfExams] = double.Parse(examScoresTextBox.Text);
            countOfExams++;
            examScoresTextBox.ResetText();
            examScoresTextBox.Focus();


            if(countOfExams >= examScores.Length)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hoise vaya");
            }


        }

        private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Array.Clear(examScores, 0, examScores.Length);
            ClearAll();
        }
        private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();                       
        }

        public void ClearAll()
        {
            examLabel.Text = "Exam:";
            examScoresTextBox.ResetText();
            numOfExamsTextBox.ResetText();

        }
        private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line of your `enterBtn_Click`,

```
countOfExams = int.Parse(numOfExamsTextBox.Text);
```

I suppose you are using `countOfExams` as the total length of the array.

Later in the second line of your `addBtn_Click`,

```
examScores[countOfExams] = double.Parse(examScoresTextBox.Text);
countOfExams++;
```

I suppose you are using `countOfExams` to track the actual number of exams. Because `countOfExams` is already set to the length, it results in `OutOfRangeException`.

Thus, I suggest you to use another variable (e.g. a local variable) for the total length of the array,

```
var size = int.Parse(numOfExamsTextBox.Text);
examScores = new double[size];
```

Answer (score 1):

double[] examScores; has been defined as array, which was never initialized if you are not calling enterBtn_Click first 
Ideally,

You should first initialize/ check if it is initialized it by

```
double[] examScores = new double[<length>];
```

also, the counter starts from 0 and not 1

If you are not sure about the length or capacity, use List

Comment: Thanks but I've initialized the array inside the enterBtn click event. The length of the array depends on numOfExamsTextBox which will be a user input.

Comment: If the number of exams if flexible, why not use List instead of array?